# deploy zip file to ftp with pipelines

Tags: webpack, ftp, yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using webpack to create a /build folder of my project. The whole project is saved in a bitbucket repo. I can't figure out how to make bitbucket pipelines upload ONLY the .zip file in the /build folder to FTP server?

Currently, pipelines save the whole project as .zip and deploys this to the FTP, which should only be the .zip in the /build folder.

Anyone who knows the answer?